# java hotkey work with window minimized

Tags: java, hotkeys, screen-capture

I created a program that will capture a picture of the screen and save it to your desired location. I have a hotkey set to the window so that when you take a picture of the screen you won't have the window in the picture. Whenever the window is minimized the hotkey will not work. Is there a solution for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Button to capture:

```
button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           cap();
       }
    });
```

cap() method:

```
private void cap(){
    try {
         Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
         Robot rt = new Robot();
         BufferedImage img = rt.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle((int)
            screen.getWidth(), (int) screen.getHeight()));
         ScreenCaptureFileChooser fc = new ScreenCaptureFileChooser();
         selectedFile = ScreenCaptureFileChooser.pic();
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", selectedFile);
         }catch (AWTException | IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(guiClassScreenCapture.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
}
```

Comment: You're wanting to respond to a keypress when your application is out of focus?

Comment: @chrylis I'm new to java. What out of focus the same as minimized programs?

Comment: `Whenever the window is minimized the hotkey will not work. Is there a solution for this problem?` not in Java. Java can only receive KeyEvents when it is the active Window. If the window is minimized then it is not active and can't receive KeyEvents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [React on global hotkey in a Java program on Windows/Linux/Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79658/react-on-global-hotkey-in-a-java-program-on-windows-linux-mac)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ScreenShot issue - excluding own app. from screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898910/screenshot-issue-excluding-own-app-from-screenshot)